# Sp2013 : customize ootb SharePoint alerts

Tags: 2013, custom-alert-templates

How to customize the email body of ootb SharePoint alerts ? I read blogs which explain s of creating a alerthandler , create copy of alert template.xml and  make changes to alertcopy.xml . then run stsadm to make alertcopy as default xml file . but after doing this I don't see any changes to alert template . anybody experience d same issue ? And how do I resolve this ?